# Block registration if email already exists in mysqli database

Tags: php, email, mysqli

Users can use the same email address for different registration.

Tried using different solutions from developers on Stack Overflow who have experienced the same problems that I have, including making the emailUsers column a UNIQUE KEY in the database table, and implementing some sort of jQuery, but not successful. Think the problem is I am missing an 'else if' block for duplicate email, but all the various ways I tried to implement this, it does not do anything.

```
<div id="signup">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-1">

                <div class="signup-left position-fixed text-center">

                    <img src="img/200.png">
                    <br><br><br>
                    <?php

                    if(isset($_GET['error']))
                    {
                        if($_GET['error'] == 'emptyfields')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Fill In All The Fields
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmailuid')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Please enter a valid email and user name
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Please enter a valid email
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invaliduid')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Please enter a valid user name
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'passwordcheck')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Passwords donot match
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'usertaken')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> This User name is already taken
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidimagetype')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Invalid image type 
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'imguploaderror')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Image upload error, please try again
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'imgsizeexceeded')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Error: </strong> Image too large
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'sqlerror')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <strong>Website Error: </strong> Contact admin to have the issue fixed
                                    </div>';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (isset($_GET['signup']) == 'success')
                    {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                <strong>Signup Successful</strong> Please Login from the login menu
                                </div>';
                    }
                ?>
        <form id="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" name="signup-submit" value="Signup">

            <br><br>

            <a href="login.php">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-2x social-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="contact.php">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x social-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

I want to be able to block a user from registering with the same email, and to generate an error message when the user tries to do this.

EXTRA INFO: Can post further, detailed methods of me trying to make the emailUsers column a UNIQUE KEY, but when I do this, new users can no longer register, even if they use a different email.

Comment: Making the relevant column unique is definitely the way. There's no reason at all that should affect new users whose e-mail is not yet in the system.

Comment: Ahh, yes. UNIQUE KEY does work. It took a while to modify this column/database properly, but I finally managed to get this working. The problem is that although the database does not update with a duplicate email thanks to modifying emailUsers UNIQUE KEY, a user can still use the email, and they will still get a prompt that they have registered, thus leading them to believe they are registered.

I am still at a loss on how to create a prompt that will link with emailUsers UNIQUE KEY if the email has not been saved. Do you have any ideas based on the code posted above?

@Utkanos

Comment: If I understand correctly, MySQL is blocking the duplication attempt but your underlying code is not taking account of such errors coming from MySQL. You don't show your actual PHP code that interfaces with the database, but that's basically what you need to do - listen for MySQL errors and react accordingly in how you respond to the user.

Comment: I have been trying to find a way to solve this issue for the past few days, but still no joy.
Yes, now that I have enabled UNIQUE KEY in the emailUsers column, MySQL doesn't save duplicate email. There are no errors generated. However, even if the database doesn't save duplicate email, the user gets a prompt saying that that user has successfully registered

If you see the original post that I made above, there was supposed to be an error generated if the user registered with a duplicate email. The error is 'usertaken' if you want to take a look.

I can post more code if you want

Comment: I'm surprised MySQL isn't producing an error on duplication attempt on a unique key. In the very least, you should be able to infer this by checking the `affected_rows` stat - this will be 1 if a row was entered, or 0 if not.

Comment: I tried looking for `affected_rows`, but to no avail. Would it be better if I contacted you so that I can give you the system @Utkanos?